# ProxyPassMatch, regex to proxy dynamic content

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have a shared hosting server with some 2000 websites on it.

I have a lightweight apache/event frontend that takes care of static content and locally proxies requests for dynamic content to a heavyweight apache/prefork/mod_php backend.

This is the regex I am using at the moment

```
ProxyPassMatch .*\.(?i)(avi|bmp|css|flv|gho|gif|ico|iso|jpg|jpeg|js|mkv|mp4|pdf|png|rar|swf|tiff|txt|zip)$ !
ProxyPassReverse / http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

However I am considering switching to this regex

```
(\.php|\/|\.html|^[^.]+|\.htm)$
```

This would proxy the following

1) anything.php

2) / or /anything/

3) anything.html

4) anything

5) anything.htm

but not the following

1) anything.PHP

2) anything.jpg

3) anything.anything

which is exactly what I want.

Can you come up with a more efficient solution to proxy anything that should be treated as dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the static content in a separate directory instead. That way you won't be tied to filenames in case you want to add some new kind of content to not be proxied.

Comment: sorry Jenny, I should have mentioned this is for a shared hosting server.

Comment: You did...but it would still be possible to have your users use a particular path for static content and do a `ProxyPassMatch` that excludes that directory.

Comment: I thought about this, the problem is that each website is built on a different CMS Joomla, phpBB, WordPress to name but a few. These have images all over the place... some of them even place images/PHP files in the same directories.

Comment: Then I can't think of something better at the moment; it's a bit too late to suggest that your customers change their entire setup...

Comment: Actually, now I *can* think of something better. Instead of not proxying, you could cache the files that shouldn't be proxied.